# Detect MouseUp after Leaving MouseDown Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouseup

Using VB.NET, Short of adding a mouseup event to every control in my form, does anybody know a way to trigger a mouseup event regardless of where the cursor is located or what control the cursor is in?

Or is there a way to see if the mouse left button is up, that way I can do on enter, if mouseup then...

Comment: web? win? wpf? silverlight? <whatever-ui-you-are-working-on-and-i-forgot-to-mention>?

Comment: I'm using visual studio, visual basic, working on a windows forms application.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Set the Capture property to True.

Comment: The mouse up event will trigger after the mouse down one. So what do you want actually?

Comment: Check the click event of the mousedown control.  Believe it or not, click actually happens when the mouse button is released.

Even though the mouse has left the control, for most controls the click event still happens.

By chance, are you trying to do a drag operation?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer, but I found the click event doesn't work if I've left the control. I've got a datagridview where on enter to the row headers, SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect and on mouseenter to the column headers, SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect. But on mouse down in either the row or columns headers I need to disable the mouseenter event, and on mouseup enable it again. The problem is my cursor will often leave the datagridview on selecting multiple headers.

Comment: Hans, thanks also for your reply, I'm going to do some research to see if I can get your answer to work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is there a way to see if the mouse left button is up, that way I can do on enter, if mouseup then...

There is a static property on the `Control` class - [`Control.MouseButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns, in the form of a flag based enum, which buttons on the mouse are currently pressed.

```
var pressedButtons = Control.MouseButtons;
if (!pressedButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
{
    // Left mouse button is not down, so do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, just tested this out and it works great. When I was trying to find an answer to my problem on the web, there were multiple questions about mouseup outside the form (not just the control), this solution would work for there problem as well.